# Xamarin forms query app.database always null?

Tags: c#, android, database, sqlite, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin forms app and added a local SQLite DB.
Followed this tutorial to get it set up.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

The database was working but now all of sudden the App.Database queries always return null. All my queries are returning null, I have posted the GetSiteAsync query below as an example.

Please see the below query always returns null.

> var site = await Database.GetSiteAsync();

All code relating to the SQLite db is posted below.

My App.xaml.cs looks as follows:

```
namespace MyApp
{
public partial class App : Application
    {
        static Database database;

        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Resources = new ResourceDictionary();

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new BeginPage());

            ConnectAsync();
        }

        public static Database Database
        {
            get
            {
                if (database == null)
                {
                    database = new 
                    Database(DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper().GetLocalFilePath("TodoSQLite.db3"));
                }
                return database;
            }
        }
        public async void ConnectAsync()
        {
            var site = await Database.GetSiteAsync();
            //Always null????
        }
    }
}
```

I have the IFileHelper interface in my MyApp Project

```
public interface IFileHelper
{
    string GetLocalFilePath(string filename);
}
```

And the FileHelper in MyApp.Android

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileHelper))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class FileHelper : IFileHelper
    {
        public string GetLocalFilePath(string filename)
        {
            string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            return Path.Combine(path, filename);
        }
    }
}
```

My Database class looks as follows:

```
namespace MyApp.Data
{
    public class Database
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

        public Database(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);;
            //database.DropTableAsync<Site>().Wait();

            database.CreateTableAsync<Site>().Wait();
        }
        public Task<Site> GetSiteAsync()
        {
            return database.Table<Site>().Where(i => i.Id == 1).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest checking that the database actually has records. based on code it should have a record with `id = 1` but it doesn't appear so given that the result returned is null.

Comment: Second, avoid using `async void` as well as mixing async/await with blocking calls like `.Wait()` or `.Result`. Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)